# How to show all the rows using grocery crud?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I want to see the people that is vendor and both in of the table `fin_vendor_client` using grocery crud.

```
 $crud->set_relation('id_vendor', 'fin_vendor_client', 'name', 
                      array('id_entity' => 1, 'type' => 'Vendor' || 'Both'));
```

But only show me the vendor of the `entity = 1` and do not show me...

Can someone help me please?

Comment: well i reach a conclusion that is best, having 2 bool for client and vendor, instead of one ENUM type, this way i can easily get vendor or client or both. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having 2 bool for client and vendor, instead of one ENUM type, this way i can easily get vendor or client or both. :)